# Histogram buckets

Tags: statistics

I saw people making the buckets of histogram like this;
1-10
10-20
20-30
30-40
where lower bound is included, but it's not true for the upper bound.
But, I also noticed people making buckets like this;
1-9
10-19
20-29

why is it the case? Is it depend on the scales of measurement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make buckets like 1-9, 10-19, 20-29, and so on, you better make sure that a measurement of 9.5 doesn't make sense. More specifically, that all your measurements necessarily are integers.

Are you measuring how many days in each month it rains, and you want to aggregate a decade or two worth of data into a histogram? Then a measurement of 9.5 doesn't make sense. So you can leave the buckets as 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-31.

Are you measuring how many millimeters of rain you get each day, and you want to aggregate a year or two of data in a histogram? Then a measurement of 9.5 makes sense, and you should have the buckets as 0-10, 10-20, 20-29, and so on.